# How to `--no-clobber` with `docker cp`? Copy file from a Docker container but not overwrite if destination already exists

Tags: docker, copy, race-condition, cp

I want to copy a file from inside a Docker container:

```
docker cp MY_CONTAINER_NAME:/path/to/file /destination/path
```

However, [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) doesn't seem to have a `--no-clobber` option like regular `cp` has. So how can I copy the file without overwriting the destination if it already exists?

Simply checking for the existence of the destination *before* running `docker cp` isn't atomic and vulnerable to race condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -o noclobber
{ > /destination/path ; } &> /dev/null

if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    echo 'already exists!'
    exit 1
fi

docker cp MY_CONTAINER_NAME:/path/to/file /destination/path
```

The `noclobber` will prevent accidental overwriting when redirecting output. The redirection will return a non-zero exit code if the file already exists.

EDIT:

I found this SO answer that uses exactly the same solution: [atomic create file if not exists from bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828544/atomic-create-file-if-not-exists-from-bash-script)

Maybe other comments will help.

Comment: well, it depends on how you check the existence of the destination. With this solution, you try to create the destination path, if it exists then the copy won't happen. Anyway it's vulnerable to race condition if you use this kind of script only in some places.

Comment: if the destination is a folder, you can use `mkdir`. Both are atomic.

Comment: as you said, currently docker cp does not support --noclobber. I offered an alternative solution to your problem. Another solution would be to copy the stuff somewhere else and then using the normal `cp --noclobber` but this would simply move the race condition problem from the destination to the temporary folder.

Comment: this solution addresses the race condition because the creation/check of the destination file is an atomic operation. If the atomic operation fails, the script ends. I suggest to test it out manually. Have this script executed 1000 times and put some random waits to simulate the possibility of a race condition.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the check and creation is atomic. However, another process might still write to the file between `{ > /destination/path ; } &> /dev/null` and `docker cp`. For that short time span I cannot differentiate if I just created the (empty) file myself or if it's been (re)created/modified by another process.

Comment: if the other process ignores the fact that the folder/file already exists, you're right. I'm assuming you're doing those checks.

Comment: well, if you don't have control on how the processes are getting executed, I'm afraid that it's not possible at the moment.